# Kafka schema-registry with JSON not working

Tags: c#, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am having problems having my schema registry for Kafka working.¨

I have the following docker compose file:

```
version: "2"
services: 
# Zookeper single mode
  zookeeper: 
    image: zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888

# Kafka single mode
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    restart: "no"
    links:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL

# Kafka schema registry
  kafka-schema-registry:
    image: bitnami/schema-registry
    hostname : localhost
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: "zookeeper:2181"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: localhost
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN: '*'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG: "true"

# Kafka topic/message gui
  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    container_name: kafka-ui
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
      - kafka-schema-registry
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper:2181
```

I use the following docker compose command:

```
 docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -p kafka up -d --build
```

Everything seems to be running fine, although when I try to make a producer and a consumer using a data entity/schema, I get this error in my log:

```
2024-01-27 10:05:15 [2024-01-27 09:05:15,162] INFO Adding listener with HTTP/2: NamedURI{uri=http://0.0.0.0:8081, name='null'} (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer:296)
2024-01-27 10:05:15 [2024-01-27 09:05:15,412] INFO Found internal listener: NamedURI{uri=http://0.0.0.0:8081, name='null'} (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry:189)
2024-01-27 10:05:15 [2024-01-27 09:05:15,413] INFO Setting my identity to version=1,host=127.0.0.1,port=8081,scheme=http,leaderEligibility=true,isLeader=false (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry:192)
2024-01-27 10:06:15 [2024-01-27 09:06:15,719] ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication:79)
2024-01-27 10:06:15 io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryException: Failed to get Kafka cluster ID
2024-01-27 10:06:15     at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.kafkaClusterId(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:1982)
```

I have tried googling 'Failed to get Kafka cluster ID' error, but I have not had any luck making it work.

This is my producer and consumer kafka config in my c# console app:

```
// Kafka producer/consumer configuration
var config = new ConsumerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
    GroupId = "my.stackoweflow.groupid",
    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
    EnableAutoCommit = false
};
var schemaRegistryUrl = "http://localhost:8081";
const string topic = "my.stackoverflow.topic";

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var myProducer = new JsonProducer<User>(config.BootstrapServers, schemaRegistryUrl, topic);
var myConsumer = new JsonConsumer<User>(config.BootstrapServers, schemaRegistryUrl, config.GroupId, topic);
```

Can someone please help shedding some light on this problem? I want my schema registry to work, assuming making my producer instantiating JsonProducer will register the User Schema in schema-registry.

My user class:

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string? FirstName{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_date")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

I am practically using this example:
https://github.com/RebeldeCuantico/kafka-schema-registry/blob/main/src/JsonFormat/Program.cs

Comment: I have written my question in confluent forum now as well: https://forum.confluent.io/t/failed-to-get-kafka-cluster-id/9938